# How do I install gitversion on Mac?

Tags: semantic-versioning, gitversion

The gitversion documentation is hard to find the answer to this simple question. How do I install this software on mac os?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is buried on the page `https://gitversion.net/docs/usage/cli/installation`

If you don't have homebrew installed, you'll need to get that first. If you already have it, run `brew install gitversion`

Comment: Another option would be to install the .Net Global Tool version of GtiVersion.  Assuming that you have the .NET Core installed, you can run `dotnet tool install GitVersion.Tool -g`